# Problem seeding Heroku database

Tags: heroku, sequelize

I'm trying to seed my Heroku production database and got the following error message:

> ERROR: insert or update on table "Posts" violate foreign key constraint "Posts_userId_fkey

The post migration file:

```
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.createTable('Posts', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      userId: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        references: {
          model: 'Users'
        }
      },
      content: {
        type: Sequelize.TEXT,
        allowNull: false
      },
      title: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(50),
        allowNull: false
      },
      photo: {
        type: Sequelize.TEXT,
        allowNull: false
      },
      categoryId: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        references: {
          model: 'Categories'
        }
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        defaultValue: Sequelize.fn('now')
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        defaultValue: Sequelize.fn('now')
      }
    });
  },
  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.dropTable('Posts');
  }
};
```

user model file:

```
 User.associate = function(models) {
    // associations can be defined here
    User.hasMany(models.Post, { foreignKey: 'userId' })
  };
```

my config file:

```
production: {
    use_env_variable: 'DATABASE_URL',
    dialect: 'postgres',
    seederStorage: 'sequelize',
    dialectOptions: {
      ssl: {
        require: true,
        rejectUnauthorized: false
      }
    }
  }
```

my post seeders:

```
return queryInterface.bulkInsert(
      "Posts",
      [
        {
          userId: 4,
          content: "Cream cheese halloumi camembert de normandie. Queso emmental melted cheese cream cheese cheese triangles the big cheese emmental blue castello. When the cheese comes out everybody's happy gouda queso fromage camembert de normandie stinking bishop rubber cheese rubber cheese. Edam cheese triangles pecorino babybel stilton. Parmesan hard cheese smelly cheese. Cheese triangles fondue macaroni cheese port-salut taleggio chalk and cheese brie cheesecake. Bavarian bergkase emmental taleggio dolcelatte fondue roquefort cheeseburger cheese slices. Fromage frais.Cheesecake cheese and wine fromage frais. Roquefort cheese triangles fromage frais stilton paneer mascarpone chalk and cheese dolcelatte. Dolcelatte who moved my cheese croque monsieur manchego taleggio cheese on toast hard cheese bocconcini. Cow everyone loves monterey jack cheesy grin smelly cheese cauliflower cheese bocconcini the big cheese. Hard cheese hard cheese.Cheese slices smelly cheese cheese on toast. Cheese strings chalk and cheese camembert de normandie cheese and biscuits red leicester cow brie cut the cheese. Cheese on toast melted cheese stilton pecorino brie st. agur blue cheese manchego cheese strings. Boursin who moved my cheese stilton paneer cheese triangles lancashire cow who moved my cheese. Who moved my cheese cauliflower cheese mascarpone say cheese.",
          title: 'First blog',
          photo: 'https://i.pinimg.com/originals/e8/67/8c/e8678c5f0b32c1a4bffae9e9c9ca41a5.jpg',
          categoryId: 1
        },
        {
          userId: 4,
          content: "Cream cheese halloumi camembert de normandie. Queso emmental melted cheese cream cheese cheese triangles the big cheese emmental blue castello. When the cheese comes out everybody's happy gouda queso fromage camembert de normandie stinking bishop rubber cheese rubber cheese. Edam cheese triangles pecorino babybel stilton. Parmesan hard cheese smelly cheese. Cheese triangles fondue macaroni cheese port-salut taleggio chalk and cheese brie cheesecake. Bavarian bergkase emmental taleggio dolcelatte fondue roquefort cheeseburger cheese slices. Fromage frais.Cheesecake cheese and wine fromage frais. Roquefort cheese triangles fromage frais stilton paneer mascarpone chalk and cheese dolcelatte. Dolcelatte who moved my cheese croque monsieur manchego taleggio cheese on toast hard cheese bocconcini. Cow everyone loves monterey jack cheesy grin smelly cheese cauliflower cheese bocconcini the big cheese. Hard cheese hard cheese.Cheese slices smelly cheese cheese on toast. Cheese strings chalk and cheese camembert de normandie cheese and biscuits red leicester cow brie cut the cheese. Cheese on toast melted cheese stilton pecorino brie st. agur blue cheese manchego cheese strings. Boursin who moved my cheese stilton paneer cheese triangles lancashire cow who moved my cheese. Who moved my cheese cauliflower cheese mascarpone say cheese.",
          title: 'Cat Ipsum',
          photo: 'https://i.pinimg.com/564x/52/d7/49/52d749ce51a1341d30ac00eb2ef712a9.jpg',
          categoryId: 2
        },
        {
          userId: 4,
          content: "Cream cheese halloumi camembert de normandie. Queso emmental melted cheese cream cheese cheese triangles the big cheese emmental blue castello. When the cheese comes out everybody's happy gouda queso fromage camembert de normandie stinking bishop rubber cheese rubber cheese. Edam cheese triangles pecorino babybel stilton. Parmesan hard cheese smelly cheese. Cheese triangles fondue macaroni cheese port-salut taleggio chalk and cheese brie cheesecake. Bavarian bergkase emmental taleggio dolcelatte fondue roquefort cheeseburger cheese slices. Fromage frais.Cheesecake cheese and wine fromage frais. Roquefort cheese triangles fromage frais stilton paneer mascarpone chalk and cheese dolcelatte. Dolcelatte who moved my cheese croque monsieur manchego taleggio cheese on toast hard cheese bocconcini. Cow everyone loves monterey jack cheesy grin smelly cheese cauliflower cheese bocconcini the big cheese. Hard cheese hard cheese.Cheese slices smelly cheese cheese on toast. Cheese strings chalk and cheese camembert de normandie cheese and biscuits red leicester cow brie cut the cheese. Cheese on toast melted cheese stilton pecorino brie st. agur blue cheese manchego cheese strings. Boursin who moved my cheese stilton paneer cheese triangles lancashire cow who moved my cheese. Who moved my cheese cauliflower cheese mascarpone say cheese.",
          title: 'Cheesecake Party',
          photo: 'https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/cheesecake-slice-with-strawberries-picture-id1205169550?k=20&m=1205169550&s=612x612&w=0&h=QqJDIpCEpGEXBFU2c-aoZKEgtU5tfFGxKxrBu1bHYww=',
          categoryId: 2
        },
        {
          userId: 5,
          content: "Cream cheese halloumi camembert de normandie. Queso emmental melted cheese cream cheese cheese triangles the big cheese emmental blue castello. When the cheese comes out everybody's happy gouda queso fromage camembert de normandie stinking bishop rubber cheese rubber cheese. Edam cheese triangles pecorino babybel stilton. Parmesan hard cheese smelly cheese. Cheese triangles fondue macaroni cheese port-salut taleggio chalk and cheese brie cheesecake. Bavarian bergkase emmental taleggio dolcelatte fondue roquefort cheeseburger cheese slices. Fromage frais.Cheesecake cheese and wine fromage frais. Roquefort cheese triangles fromage frais stilton paneer mascarpone chalk and cheese dolcelatte. Dolcelatte who moved my cheese croque monsieur manchego taleggio cheese on toast hard cheese bocconcini. Cow everyone loves monterey jack cheesy grin smelly cheese cauliflower cheese bocconcini the big cheese. Hard cheese hard cheese.Cheese slices smelly cheese cheese on toast. Cheese strings chalk and cheese camembert de normandie cheese and biscuits red leicester cow brie cut the cheese. Cheese on toast melted cheese stilton pecorino brie st. agur blue cheese manchego cheese strings. Boursin who moved my cheese stilton paneer cheese triangles lancashire cow who moved my cheese. Who moved my cheese cauliflower cheese mascarpone say cheese.",
          title: 'Tell Me A Joke',
          photo: 'https://st2.depositphotos.com/1010146/9831/i/950/depositphotos_98319240-stock-photo-laughing-man-closeup.jpg',
          categoryId: 1
        },
      ],
      {}
    );
  },
```

Why is it producing that message?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, every Post ***must*** be linked to a corresponding (no pun intended) User.

This is what the Foreign Key is enforcing.
It *will not* allow you to create a Post that contains a userId that does not match an existing User.

You don't show a "seeder" for the Users.
Is it as simple as you're trying to "seed" the Posts *before* "seeding" the Users?